# Using a local database

Tags: c#, database, local

I'm busy writing a small app and I only want a database to load small amounts of data, in other words I don't need the functionality of SQL.

So I've installed filehelpers, but it seems very limited in the sense that I can read/write and even append data, but it seem impossible to delete one row of data in a table?

Does anyone know how to do this with filehelpers or point me to a different solution where I can just add a local db to my app without any other external software required?

PS. My visual studio does not have the "create local db" from the item selection.

Comment: What is a "filehelpers"?

Comment: filehelpers is a app to load data in and out of a text file or whatever.  http://www.filehelpers.net/examples/

Comment: @UweKeim - I'm guessing this http://www.filehelpers.net/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For something like this, I'd use an embedded SQLite database.  It gives you the best of both worlds, one file database for local data and most of the features of SQL.

See here: https://sqlite.org/

On their download page, they have lots of stuff and a plugin for VS:

https://sqlite.org/download.html

Comment: I've checked it out a bit before, but I'm a bit confused as how it works or even installs. I'm used to the Management studio of SQL, and it seems like sql lite works completely different?

Comment: This is basically the best approach.  This embeds a small .db file with your application (the database--basically comma separated rows) and allows you to use SQL commands to add/delete rows as you wish.  You may use direct SQL, Entity Framework, Dapper or whatever flavor ORM you prefer. I personally hate VS SQL tools, but you may have to go 3rd party for a better management tool to use on SQLite.

Comment: Thanx for all the help, I think I'm going to have to read up a bit more on SQL lite, I know a lot of people are using it, so there must be a reason for that. Thanx again!!